# Windows 7 gets automatically deactivated and SQL server 2008 gets automatically uninstalled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-7

In my office there is one machine running Windows 7 32BIT Professional and SQL Server Express 2008 along with others software are installed. But the problem is in certain course of time Windows gets automatically deactivated and SQL server gets uninstalled, while other microsoft products are performing well. I have already reactivated the windows and installed SQL server on that machine atleast 3 - 4 times, but problem still persist. Please help in this regard.

regards,
Snehashis Ghosh

Comment: Are they legit copies of the software? What process is deactivating them?

Comment: Both windows and sql server are true licensed copy. Can't understand what process actually deactivating them.System is totally virus free and protected using KAV (Licensed copy). Please help.

Comment: might be better off asking this on: http://superuser.com/

Comment: is this happens when you are offline too ??

Comment: not tried on offline state. system is connected to domain and after switch on always online.